# gnuradio-companion will not run due to gtk_init error

Tags: gtk, gnuradio

My issue is very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860103/gnuradio-in-docker-gtk-stylecontext-add-provider-for-screen-typeerror-argumen), however I am running gnuradio on Ubuntu local to my windows machine, rather than docker. When I enter the command `gnuradio-companion &`, I get the following error

```
Gtk init_check failed. GRC might not be able to start a GUI.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 103, in <module>
    run_main()
  File "/usr/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 96, in run_main
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/main.py", line 73, in main
    from .gui.Platform import Platform
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/Platform.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import canvas
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/canvas/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .param import Param
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/canvas/param.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .. import ParamWidgets, Utils, Constants, Actions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/ParamWidgets.py", line 61, in <module>
    add_style_provider()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/gui/ParamWidgets.py", line 54, in add_style_provider
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
TypeError: Argument 0 does not allow None as a value

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo gnuradio-companion
```

I found another similar issue (which regarded gtk_init issues), which suggested modifying the gnuradio-companion file, to bypass the error message and non-opening of the graphical application, however I would rather not bypass a problem rather than fix it.
I am quite new to Ubuntu and gnuradio, so any help would be appreciated.